# Select nearest location in a range of time

Tags: python, sql, search, redis, geospatial

## Case study:

I'm creating a service to display taxi available in a range of time near to the user

I have a database containing the taxi availability data

```
id | lat | long | availableFrom | availableTo
n  | n   | n    | timestamp     | timestamp
```

And I'm using a Redis instance to store geospatial data to make fast geospatial queries

```
taxi
0) taxiId
0) 0) lat
   1) long
```

What I need is to retrieve the taxiId and coordinates to display taxis on a map.

I tough to create a query for taxis in a time range in the SQL database and next merge it with the Redis results but is highly inefficient.

What I can currently do with this configuration is querying for taxis near me, but I can't figure out an *efficient* way to also filter them by time range.

So how can I retrieve from the database in an efficient way taxis near to the given coordinates that are available in a range of time?
Is using only SQL the best way?
Is there any service or library to do this?

Comment: How many results are we talking here? if SQL is inefficient for doing the filtering, have you tried getting all the results and using Python itself to do the filtering? And how inefficient is your current approach? What necessitates you improving its efficiency?

Comment: Assuming in the database there are 1MLN taxis and I make a request for taxis in a range of 50km in a range of time n1 to n2 with 1k results, I would have to tailor the geopositional data from redis with the data from SQL loosing some response time. I'm just exercising to write efficent apps.

Comment: Alright that kind of answers some of my questions but I still wonder what the level inefficiency is, like how slow is it?

Comment: Almost 400ms but i think is a bit high...

Comment: So filtering out 1 million taxis by time and location takes 400ms? That's about 400ns per taxi. Doesn't seem too bad honestly. What would be a more reasonable number to you?

Comment: The point is if it scales up, I think the loop I use to tailor the data it would become slow

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RediSearch module](https://redis.io/commands/ft.create/) allows you to combine NUMERIC (timestamp) and GEO (lat,long) filters in the same Redis request.